# R: how to find corresponding value in different columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and I really got stuck on stuff, which may seem easy to you. I have a dataframe which have a huge amount of data like AGE, which is related to a particular person so is repeated. I had to divide it into ranges and see how many people are in each group. So I have this 
`

```
[,1]
(1,23]  5912
(23,26] 5579
(26,28] 3314
(28,33] 6693
(33,37] 4682
(37,41] 4514
(41,46] 5169
(46,51] 4812
(51,57] 4236
(57,76] 4031`
```

Now I have another column G/B which indicates if the person is BAD or GOOD (as 1,0, respectively)
It is required to calculate how many of 1s and 0s, i.e 'bad's and 'good'sin each group of people of different ages.
So data should be something like

```
           Total    Bad   Good
`(1,23]    5912    2912   3000 `.
```

ect. 
Hope to get help with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[,list(Total=.N, Bad=sum(GB), Good=sum(!GB)), keyby=range]

#       range Total Bad Good
# 1:    (0,1]    16   7    9
# 2:   (1,23]   257 132  125
# 3:  (23,26]    29  16   13
# 4:  (26,28]    19   8   11
# 5:  (28,33]    60  34   26
# 6:  (33,37]    52  30   22
# 7:  (37,41]    41  19   22
# 8:  (41,46]    56  25   31
# 9:  (46,51]    65  27   38
#10:  (51,57]    57  28   29
#11:  (57,76]   196 110   86
#12:  (76,85]   101  44   57
#13: (85,100]    51  24   27
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 dat1 %>%
      group_by(range) %>%
      summarise(Total=n(), Bad=sum(GB), Good=sum(!GB))
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
  res <- do.call(`data.frame`,aggregate(GB~range, dat1,
                FUN=function(x) c(length(x), sum(x), sum(!x))))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(AGE= sample(1:90, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                         GB=sample(0:1, 1000, replace=TRUE))

dat1 <- transform(dat, range=cut(AGE, 
           breaks=c(0,1,23,26,28,33,37,41,46,51,57,76,85,100)))
```